# Can CRM have multiple urls that are handled differently through ADFS

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, adfs, adfs2.1

This is just a question to anyone that has been involved with CRM & ADFS installations.

I was wondering if its possible for CRM have multiple urls that are handled differently through ADFS?

so, if their staff come in from their internal network, then they use one URL, that does integrated auth login from their machine but if you come in from internet(External), then they are prompted for login auth?

All servers sit on the same domain

Any references to material or information on how to set this up would be a great help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the preferred approach.

There is a good blog with [the step-by-step process](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dynamicspts/archive/2012/08/08/configuring-ifd-for-crm-2011.aspx).  There are a couple of gotcha's...the ADFS installation has to be on the Default IIS Website (ID=1).  Second, having a wildcard cert makes the installation easier.

Comment: Thank you Chris that's great. I will take a look through your suggestions & mark as answer if its what I am looking for.